# Fastest way to post-process documents in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I would like to save documents to Cosmos DB using either Mongo or SQL API.

I need to calculate some kind of auto-incremented field, so that I can order the documents based on the field. Let's call the field 'DocumentOrder'.

However, calculating the field doesn't have to block the insert transaction. Inserting the documents should be as fast as possible and atomicity here is not required.

**What would be the best option to post-process the inserted documents in order to calculate the field, so that the delay between insert and update the calculated field is as small as possible.**

Triggered Azure function? WebJob? CosmosDB PostTrigger?

The requirements are:

1. It has to be reliable - every document must be post processed eventually.
2. It has to happen in deterministic order, so that document with calculated value DocumentOrder=1 will be saved before document with DocumentOrder=2.

What I want to achieve? At the end I need a query that will return documents always in the same order, approximately as they were inserted.

Comment: As written, this question is too broad - lots of ways to post-process (or even pre-process): queues, triggers, etc. You'd need to benchmark. That said: Any reason why you can't add a timestamp property to each new document, capturing insert time (maybe as ticks?) and then sort by that property? This would completely avoid the added RU cost of updating documents later.

Comment: Because if the database collection is partitioned, timestamp is not reliable. There can be a time shift between partition, or region